# java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v4/view/ViewPager$MyAccessibilityDelegate.class

Tags: android, duplicates

I'm new in Android programming, please help me.

I've got an error like this when I'm compiling my application :

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v4/view/ViewPager$MyAccessibilityDelegate.class

and this is my gradle file:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


    android {
        compileSdkVersion 17
        buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ecs.google.maps.v2.actionbarsherlock"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 17
        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    }

}

configurations { all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4' }

dependencies {
    compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
    compile ('com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:+') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }

    compile 'com.astuetz:pagerslidingtabstrip:1.0.0'
    compile ('com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.3+') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }

    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.1'
    compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }



    compile files('libs/google-http-client-1.15.0-rc.jar')
    compile files('libs/google-http-client-android-1.15.0-rc.jar')
    compile files('libs/google-http-client-jackson2-1.15.0-rc.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpclient-4.0.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpcore-4.0.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/jackson-core-2.1.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/jackson-core-asl-1.9.11.jar')


}
```

I already removed all duplicate support-v4 files in my lib folder.

Can you tell what is wrong with my code? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below script does not always excludes support-v4

```
compile ('some-module') {
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
}
```

Because the module name could be different.
So, you need to find out the module name (ARTIFACT_ID) first in-order to exclude the right one.

In my case, adding **RecyclerView** as my project dependency caused below errors.

> duplicate entry:
>   android/support/v4/view/ViewPager$MyAccessibilityDelegate.class

and

> duplicate entry:
>   android/support/v4/hardware/display/DisplayManagerCompat.class

I found out the modules using gradle task **androidDependencies**.

[image]

Executing this task will display the dependency tree (reference image below).

[image]

Then removed the unwanted or duplicate modules.

```
compile ('com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+') {
   exclude module: "support-core-ui"
   exclude module: "support-compat"
}
```